# Is there a way to print Json data in multiple rows?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

This is my code.
JSON data was requested from the server and changed to pretty print format.

```
function getHTML(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var num = 291;
var url = "" + num;
var options = {
      'method': 'GET',
      'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  }

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());

// Json  pretty-print
var infoJsonString = JSON.parse(response)
var PrettyJsonString = JSON.stringify(infoJsonString,null,2);
Logger.log(PrettyJsonString);

sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(PrettyJsonString);

}
```

```
{"service": {"cmd": 0,"error": 0,"msg": null,"route": "${***}"},"result": {"Width": 5,"Count": 40,"tArray": [0,0,0,0,0]}
```

```
{
  ""service"": {
    ""cmd"": 0,
    ""error"": 0,
    ""msg"": null,
    ""route"": ""${}""
  },
  ""result"": {
    ""Width"": 5,
    ""Count"": 40,
    ""Array"": [
      [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ]
}
```

I have succeeded changing the json data.
However, when pasting on a sheet, all the data goes into one cell.
Can I put data one per line?

This is the current execution result.
[image]

This is the result I want.
[image]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object) ?

Comment: Have you tried using the sheet method split [text to columns](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6325535?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and then using the [transpose function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) to move it to row?